# How to get a object from a view while using a django.test TestCase

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, templates, view

I am trying to access the object 'wines' that would be sent to a template. Basicaly, in this example I have wines that are sold by bottles, glasses or both. The first test I am on should be able to retrieve all 3 wines in a object called 'wines' that is sent to the template. (create_wine() is a custom Wine.objects.create() method).

If you notice, I am using django.test import TestCase so I have a self.client object to use. Also, if you notice, I am showing you where I am trying to degub at the '(debug)' text.

What I really want to get is the prerendered json. It seems to me that view renders the html using the object to create what html it needs and returns that. So how do I access this prerendered object?

The thing is I am going to be using the same view to render these wine objects. I would like to use the same template if possible, which would mean sending data to the view and rewriting it so it grabs the correct wines before rendering. I think this is ok. If this breaks django methodology, I am all ears.

Is there another way to go aboutt this or am I very close?

## Code

#### VIEWs

```
def wine_list(request):
    wines = Wine.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    return render(request, 'wine/wine_list.html', {'wines': wines})
```

#### URLs

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'wine.views.wine_list', name='wine_list'),
    url(r'^bottle/$', 'wine.views.wine_list', name='wine_list_bottle'),
    url(r'^glass/$', 'wine.views.wine_list', name='wine_list_glass'),
    url(r'^([0-9]+)/$', 'wine.views.wine_details', name='wine_detail'),
]
```

#### UT

```
    from django.test import TestCase

    def test_both_wine_glass_and_bottle_pull_different_objects(self):

        # Todo: how to pull object info from view
        self.create_wine(container="bottle")
        self.create_wine(container="glass")
        self.create_wine(container="both")

        request = self.client.get("/wine/")
        from wine.views import wine_list
        result = wine_list(request)
(debug) result

        # assert wine/ wine is both glass and bottle
        # assert wine/glass/ wine is only both or glass wines
        # assert wine/bottle/ wine is only both or bottle wines
        self.fail("finish the test")
```

#### 'result' at (debug)

```
result = {HttpResponse} <HttpResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">
 _charset = {NoneType} None
 _closable_objects = {list} <class 'list'>: []
 _container = {list} <class 'list'>: [b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n    <meta charset="UTF-8">\n    <title>Wine List</title>\n    \n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/wine/reset.css">\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/wine/menu.css">\n</head>\n<bod
 _handler_class = {NoneType} None
 _headers = {dict} {'content-type': ('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')}
 _reason_phrase = {NoneType} None
 charset = {str} 'utf-8'
 closed = {bool} False
 content = {bytes} b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n    <meta charset="UTF-8">\n    <title>Wine List</title>\n    \n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/wine/reset.css">\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/wine/menu.css">\n</head>\n<body>\n    <header c
 cookies = {SimpleCookie} 
 reason_phrase = {str} 'OK'
 status_code = {int} 200
 streaming = {bool} False
```

#### Other passing unit tests (if these help at all)

```
    self.create_wine(container="both")

    bottle = Wine.bottle.all()
    glass = Wine.glass.all()
    both = Wine.objects.all()

    self.assertEqual(2, len(bottle))
    self.assertEqual(2, len(glass))
    self.assertEqual(3, len(both))

def test_both_wine_glass_and_bottle_pull_the_same_template(self):
    bottle_list = self.client.get('/wine/bottle/')
    glass_list = self.client.get('/wine/glass/')
    both_list = self.client.get('/wine/')

    self.assertTemplateUsed(both_list, 'wine/wine_list.html')
    self.assertTemplateUsed(bottle_list, 'wine/wine_list.html')
    self.assertTemplateUsed(glass_list, 'wine/wine_list.html')
```

### simple template wine_list.html

```
{% extends 'wine/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <section id="wine_content">
        <div class="cards">

            {% for wine in wines %}
            <div class="card">
                <a href="/wine/{{ wine.id }}">
                    <h4>{{ wine.name }}</h4>
                    <p>{{ wine.vintage }}</p>
                    <p>{{ wine.description}}</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    </section>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misunderstood how the test client works. When you call `self.client.get("/wine/")`, it simulates a request to `/wine/`, and calls your `wine_list` view. You don't have to call `wine_list` manually.

The `client.get()` call returns a response. You can then make test assertions using the response, and fetch items from [`response.context`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Response.context).

```
    response = self.client.get("/wine/")
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)  # check 200 OK response
    wines = response.context['wines']  # this is the list of wines you included in the context
    # check that wines is as you expected.
    for wine in wines:
        # All wines should be active
        self.assertTrue(wine.is_active)
    ...
```